# custom json value with .replace give undifined output

Tags: jquery, json

I have json like this :

```
var data = {
"items":[
{
"id":"asd01231987391",
"sku":"ABC-0128712",
"product":"product abc",
"desc":"this is abc product",
"price":1200,
"qty":1
}
]
}1400;
```

and i use replace for edit/custom the '1400' value to "total":1400,so i can get value from 2 rows json, whit this code:

```
var Total = data+"]]";
var resTotal = Total.replace("}]}", '}],"total":');
var resTotal2 = resTotal.replace("]]", "}");
var resTotal1 = resTotal2; 


console.log(resTotal1.items);
console.log(resTotal1.total);
```

but the output from 2 console still give "undifined" result.

the final result must be like this :
from console 1 = resTotal1.items:

```
var res = resTotal1.items;
    $.each(res, function(i, item) {
    
    ... loop the json from items ..
                                }
```

from console 2:
its just for display the 1400;

this my jsfiddle

[JSON CUSTOM](https://jsfiddle.net/133p8fc3/)

Comment: what you are trying to add data in json is completly wrong. Tell us what final result will look like? (Add that in your question)

Comment: Thats not a valid json or js object

Comment: @AlivetoDie ya i know this not valid json, the json data i get from the input text and i get the value to loop process, .. i have update the result will look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert `data` to string first before string replace, then convert it back to JSON.

```
var Total = data.toString()+"]]";
var resTotal = Total.replace("}]}", '}],"total":');
var resTotal2 = resTotal.replace("]]", "}");
var resTotal1 = resTotal2; 
var resTotal_final = JSON.parse(resTotal1);


$(".resx").append('<span>'+resTotal_final.total+'</span>' );
```

```js
var data = '{"items":[{"id":"asd01231987391","sku":"ABC-0128712","product":"product abc","desc":"this is abc product","price":1200,"qty":1}]}1400';

var Total = data.toString() + "]]";
var resTotal = Total.replace("}]}", '}],"total":');
var resTotal2 = resTotal.replace("]]", "}");
var resTotal1 = resTotal2;
var resTotal_final = JSON.parse(resTotal1);

$(".resx").append('<span>' + resTotal_final.total + '</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resx">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1asyozcf/3/

Answer (score 2):

I think it's invalid JSON format. Anyway I think this will be helpful.

```
var data = '{"items":[{"id":"asd01231987391","sku":"ABC-0128712","product":"product abc","desc":"this is abc product","price":1200,"qty":1}]}1400';

    var Total = data+"]]";
    var resTotal = Total.replace("}]}", '}],"total":');
    var resTotal2 = resTotal.replace("]]", "}");
    var resTotal1 = resTotal2; 

    // Use JSON.parse();

    console.log(JSON.parse(resTotal1).total);
    console.log(JSON.parse(resTotal1).items);
```

Answer (score 1):

You JSON is in wrong format

```
var data = {
        "items":[
            {
                "id":"asd01231987391",
                "sku":"ABC-0128712",
                "product":"product abc",
                "desc":"this is abc product",
                "price":1200,
                "qty":1
            }
        ],
        "total": 1400
    };
```

Hope this will be your json data. To get items use `data.items` and for total use `data.total`

```js
var data = {
        "items":[
            {
                "id":"asd01231987391",
                "sku":"ABC-0128712",
                "product":"product abc",
                "desc":"this is abc product",
                "price":1200,
                "qty":1
            }
        ],
        "total": 1400
    };

    console.log("Items...");
    console.log(data.items);
    console.log("Total...");
    console.log(data.total);
```

**UPDATE: (BASED ON THE COMMENT)**

If your input is string and the format is as you defined, then first make it valid json string then decode to valid json object

```js
var data =  '{"items":[{"id":"asd01231987391","sku":"ABC-0128712","product":"product abc","desc":"this is abc product","price":1200,"qty":1}]}1400';

var formattedJSON = data.replace("}]}", "}], \"total\":")+"}";
data = JSON.parse(formattedJSON);

console.log("Items...");
console.log(data.items);
console.log("Total...");
console.log(data.total);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the var data must be like in my question.

Comment: is that a string value. If so please show the string value that you are getting. You can't have a json object like that.That endup with an error with invalid syntax

Comment: i get from input text like this {"items":[{"id":"asd01231987391","sku":"ABC-0128712","product":"product abc","desc":"this is abc product","price":1200,"qty":1}]}1400

Comment: Updated the answer please check the UPDATED part

Comment: sory i don't know where the first give the correct answer, but your code work and i give +1 to thankyou very much

Comment: No problem.Always go for the simplest and flexible solution